# Migrating existing document system into Sharepoint; how hard is this?

Tags: sharepoint, migration, legacy, import

I have a document system called eDrawer (by LSSP Corp).  We have around 100,000 documents in this system.  It can export into a folder structure, and with each exported PDF, it will export a text file which has the metadata.  Theorhetically, everthing is there for automating an import into another system.

I have some .NET background, but havne't developed in Sharepoint yet.

What am I looking at here?  Not a big deal?  Impossible?  or what?

I am thinking that somehow a sharepoint solution could iterate through the files in the directory structure, pickup the metadata in the files and insert the records into the library.

Any thoughts on this greatly appreciated.  I am seeking out consulting on this, and trying to weight the cost of that with the cost of learning how to code it myself.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint has a pretty comprehensive model for uploading files and metadata using its internal object model. [This open source tool does it](http://spfileupload.codeplex.com/).

The real issue is always the planning ahead. Little things can come back to haunt you later. Such as the fact that by default someone viewing a document library will only [get back the first 5000 items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dinaayoub/archive/2010/04/22/sharepoint-2010-how-to-change-the-list-view-threshold.aspx).

Read the [White paper: Working with largs lists in Office SharePoint Server 2007](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813%28office.12%29.aspx) before you start.
I would also reccommend you plan and [implement a custom content type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff630942.aspx) or two for the data.

So the technical part is not too hard, but the planning requires a little work and quite a bit of reading if you are coming into SharePoint from scratch.

Don't forget to [plan for search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263400.aspx).